# Highlight Pie in PieChart

Tags: plotting

`PieChart` has the nice functionality of highlighting a single pie when you click on it. It is then sticking out a little.
See the following example:

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

Now, if I click on the green Pie it starts to stick out.

[image]

Is there any way of achieving this programmatically? I browsed through the Options of `PieChart` but couldn't find anything. I want to automatically create a number of plots with highlighted sections and save them automatically without having to click on them manually each time.

Comment: There is DynamicModule created which scoped variables are only those responsibile for this. Initial values are set to `False`, each click changes it to `True` etc. If you can reconstruct those boxes so that initial value of desired variable is `True` then it will start as highlighted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this perhaps. Thanks to halmir for pointing out that multiple highlighted elements might be useful.

```
pieHighlight[chart_, n_] := chart /. DynamicModule[init_, body__] :> 
 (ReplacePart[Hold[init], Thread @ {1, n, 2} -> True] /. 
     Hold[x_] :> DynamicModule[x, body])
```

e.g.

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3}] ~pieHighlight~ 2
```

[image]

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3}] ~pieHighlight~ {1, 2}
```

[image]

Comment: nice! you could change  {1, n, 2} -> True to {1, #, 2} & /@ Flatten[{n}] -> True to allow multiple open pie. i.e, PieChart[{1, 2, 3}]~pieHighlight~{1, 3}

Comment: @halmir, good idea to allow multiple highlighted sections, but I prefer `Thread@{1, n, 2}`